# jQuery FullCalendar event overlap (multiple event same line)

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to have many events to fit on the same line.

It seems by default fullcalendar doesn't support overlap, when creating two events on the same m,d,h parameters

I tried to set the width to a smaller value in order for the event divs to align on the same line but didn't work

The target is to do:

- several events on the same line for when on the same m,d,h combination
- one dummy label events aligned on the left to indicate the exact hour + info for all events in the same m,d,h combination/line -

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: css attribute "inline-block" doesn't have an effect. And I don't think the events must be aligned manually using x,y coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the following:

- when using the theme.html example, events overlap
- this is because either allDay:false or date's end property is set
- this only works for day view, in month view events are still stacked event if css width is set!

So by using the theme.html template, and on the day view, events are ok

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I don't know if it's really a bug or just an unexpected behavior of FullCalendar.
I've created a new "issue" on the "issue tracker" for this.

https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2148&thanks=2148&ts=1399935301

Hope I've helped in something.

Comment: Interesting..thanks. But I'm referring to the calendar month view. I just can get two events on the same time appear on the same line

Comment: found it! posted solution. can you please test it on your side?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `slotEventOverlap:false`?

See [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/slotEventOverlap/).